# Dedup rows of a mirrored column using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL, assuming I have a table with First Name and Last Name,

```
FName - LName
John  - Paul 
Paul  - John 
Alice - Peter 
Peter - Alice
```

So if you see every row will have duplicate entry but in reverse.

I would like to select the rows in such a way that only one of the rows is selected for each unique entry (Doesn't matter which one).

My resulting table should be like:

```
FName - LName
John  - Paul
Peter - Alice
```

There is more than one correct result, but I hope you got the point.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is that one column with 2 values separated by a hyphen or 2 columns (fname/lname)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       least(fName, lName) fName,
       greatest (FName, lName) lName
  FROM table
```

This will do it. Your first names will come before the associated last names in the collatino.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, assuming there are always 2 duplicates, no more, no less:

This assumes your table has one column with the 2 values separated by a hyphen.

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c04fae/2/0

```
select
   min(col_lr) as de_duplicated
from
   (
      select
         x.col as col_lr,
         count(y.col) + count(z.col) as grp
      from
         tbl x
      left join tbl y on x.col < y.col
      left join tbl z on concat(right(x.col, length(x.col) - locate(' - ', x.col) - 2), ' - ', substr(x.col, 1, locate(' - ', x.col) - 1)) < z.col
      group by
         x.col
   ) x
group by
   grp
```

It establishes a composite rank in ABC order (for both left to right, and right to left) within the table, giving that group value the same for both duplicated rows, at which point you can just select the first of the two.